# accessory tick on uitableviewcell not showing in some instances

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have two tableviews, one has several tableview cells each cell opens the same subview but initalized with new data..

There are around about 100 - 200 entries into the table and I have a accessory view that is a tick that when a cell is selected it ticks the cell then loads the main view again.

If I select that same cell to get the same dataset back it loads the previously selected cell in the middle of the screen (so it knows its index path) however the tick "depending on how deep in the list" will or will not be visible..

It tends to work in about the top 30/40% of the table but anything lower the tick will not be visible... that is unless I go back and forth getting deeper and deeper each time then sometimes I can get the tick to appear in the deeper part of the tableview.. Would anyone know why this is happening?

Has anyone had something of this nature happen to them before?

At further investigation I think something is going wrong inside this method..

First of all, in the subview once the user selects a cell this method is called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //pops current view from the navigatoin stack

    //accesses selected cells content
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // now you can use cell.textLabel.text

    //This if statment is based off which cell was selected in the parent view so that it knows which cell to pass the data back to
    if (parentViewSelectedIndexPath.section == 0) {
        if (parentViewSelectedIndexPath.row == 0) {
            manufactureCellTextLabel = cell.textLabel.text; //passing label text over to NSString for use with delegate (check "viewwilldissapear")
            [[self delegate] setManufactureSearchFields:manufactureCellTextLabel withIndexPath:indexPath]; //This is where I pass the value back to the mainview
        }
// a few more If statements for the other methods I can pass data too.


//--- this if block allows only one cell selection at a time
    if (oldCheckedData == nil) { // No selection made yet
        oldCheckedData = indexPath;
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *formerSelectedcell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedData]; // finding the already selected cell
        [formerSelectedcell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark]; // 'select' the new cell
        oldCheckedData = indexPath;
    }   
}
```

This passes Index path over to the main view method...

```
   - (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSString *)cellLabeltext withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
    {
        manufactureSearchObjectString = cellLabeltext;
        manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabels so you can see the value.
    }
```

//Which then sets the manufactureResultIndexPath that is used in the next method to pass it back to the subview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    //--- Idendify selected indexPath (section/row)
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        //--- Get the subview ready for use
        VehicleResultViewController *vehicleResultViewController = [[VehicleResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VehicleResultViewController" bundle:nil];
        // ...
        //--- Sets the back button for the new view that loads
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vehicleResultViewController animated:YES];

        [vehicleResultViewController setDelegate:self];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            vehicleResultViewController.title = @"Manufacture";
            [vehicleResultViewController setRequestString:@"ID.xml"]; //sets the request string in searchResultsViewController
            vehicleResultViewController.dataSetToParse = @"ID"; // This is used to controll what data is shown on subview... logic
            [vehicleResultViewController setAccessoryIndexPath:manufactureResultIndexPath]; //sends indexpath back to subview for accessory tick
            vehicleResultViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        }


//etc etc
}
```

And finaly I pass it to the method in my subview that passes the indexpath to oldCheckedData

```
- (void)setAccessoryIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myLastIndexPath
{
                oldCheckedData = myLastIndexPath;
                [self.tableView reloadData]; //<<---- this is where I reload the table to show the tick...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `cell.accessoryType =` lines to the `willDisplayCell:` delegate function like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // You can move this one here too:
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // no blue selection

    if (indexPath == oldCheckedData) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } 
}
```

I read that the `willDisplayCell:` method should be used for any basic visual related modifications to a cell like `selectionStyle`/`accessoryType`, and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method for cell data related operations like setting text, images, etc...

Comment: okay thankyou I will try.. because i noticed when I was debugging that ifstatment it gets called for every cell in the current view.. so seems pretty inefficient... I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: @C.Johns Cool, and if it is still broken can you post the code where you are setting `oldCheckedData`.  The `if` check against `oldCheckedData` might be broken from something happening to `oldCheckedData` during the loading of the table.

Comment: okay so added that in and its doing exactly the same as it was doing before .. showing some ticks up high but not down low... Will post the code in order of how its called now.,, thankyou for helping me hopefully you see somthing I have not.

Comment: @C.Johns Join up in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4252/room-for-chown-and-c-johns

Comment: Hey Chown, thanks for the help the other day.. I am still having the issue after implementing a bunch of different fixes.. but have decided to move on and come back to this later... what a pain in the ars.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this issue, if turned out the in my case the cell has a accessoryview set. This snippet withh ensure the view is removed.

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

..logic here to to determine if cell should be selected...

if ( cell.accessoryView != nil) {
    cell.accessoryView?.removeFromSuperview()
    cell.accessoryView = nil
}
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
```